# Modal box wont open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an modal box like this, problem is that when i click on the button `DETAILS` that should open modal box, nothig happens, my file where i have modal is oppened in chrome console, but nothing is displayed. It is working when i have everything from `<div class="modal-content">` in separated file, however if i want to group it together i cannot get it to work.

```
<div class="container">

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="itemBox" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">


      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
     <div class="modal-body display-content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <?php while($stmt->fetch()) : ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><img src=<?php echo $image;?> class="image-responsive">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <form  method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" max=<?=$maxquantity?> min="0" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="<?=($maxquantity > 0) ? 1 : 0?>"/>
                            <input type="submit" class="add-to-basket btn btn-success" <?php if(!($maxquantity > 0)) {?> disabled <?php } ?> name="add-to-basket" Value=<?php if(!($maxquantity > 0)) {?>"Out of stock" <?php }else{?>"Add to cart"<?php } ?> />
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="desc">
                        <p><b>Product name:</b> <?php echo $name;?></p>
                        <h4>Description</h4>
                        <p><?php echo $description;?></p>
                        <hr>
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>  
    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

And I want to open it and display its content with this JS

```
$('.show-modal').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {modalID : product_id},
        url: 'includes/getID.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#itemBox").attr('data-id',product_id)
            $("#itemBox").modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).find(".modal-content").html(data)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can u see any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, if i console.log(data) it outputs the <div class="container"> content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.show-modal').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {"modalID" : product_id},
        url: 'includes/getID.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#itemBox").attr('data-id',product_id);
            $("#itemBox").find(".modal-body").html(data);
            $("#itemBox").modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't display anything.

Comment: `console.log(data)` . What is the output?

Comment: <div class="container"> from OP, so the modal box

Comment: So you should put that inside the `modal-body`. Try this:
`$("#itemBox").find(".modal-body").html(data);`

Comment: @KinshukLahiri you should mention necessary little bit details too with code but not only code.

Comment: @Leothelion just need to change that line of code with the one mentioned above. Also updated the answer.  :)

Comment: In the console window type this and provide the output `$("#itemBox").find(".modal-body").length;`

Comment: @KinshukLahiri you did not get my point. Whenever you are giving answer on SO, try to add some details too so other user will also get the point of yours.